# jQuery Tools: making the tab pane height changeable

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-tools

I've removed the height of div.pane and .carousel div, so that they expand in height to fit longer H3s... but now the panel (eg the border around them) has collapsed... and can't work out if/where I need a clearfloat...

http://jsfiddle.net/fJQmU/8/

Removing position:absolute from .carousel div fixes this... but breaks the animation

(PS. Also have a problem with a 1px gap underneath the right of the second tab when selected)

Comment: PS. Removing position:absolute from .carousel div fixes this... but breaks the animation :(

Comment: Could you post your code in the question so that this question will still be helpful even after the jsFiddle link dies?

Answer (score 0):

In that case just add this jquery code. That will solve the problem

```
$(".carousel").height($(".carousel div").height());
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/fJQmU/14/)

Comment: Sorry that's my lazy coding, I did that to disable the height (temporarily)